# Unable to load DLL 'SQLite.Interop.dll' when using binaries from system.data.sqlite.org

Tags: c#, sqlite, dll

I thought I start with SQLite today but I can't do anything as even the instantiation of my SQLiteConnection fails with reason `Unable to load DLL 'SQLite.Interop.dll'`.

Line is `SQLiteConnection connec = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" + dbfile);` and `string dbfile = "database.sqlite3";`

Problem here is that I can't find the dll anywhere. I downloaded the DLLs version 1.0.113.0 for .NET Standard 2.1 (.NET Core 3.0) and it comes with System.Data.SQLite.dll, System.Data.SQLite.EF6.dll and testef6.dll but no other DLLs. Where do I find the missing library?

Thanks!

Comment: There is a NuGet for SQLite.  Try using that (Under Tools->NuGet Package Manager).

Comment: will my app still be fully portable just by copying my folder? Never used NuGet before

Comment: When you compile, all DLLs, including those from the NuGet, will get copied to the compile folder, so you will be able to copy all those files for simple deployment to a Windows computer.

Comment: so I installed it from NuGet (yes I got the full package from Microsoft) but I can't find the System.Data.SQLite namespace anymore.